# Which report is sent to Canonical after installation?

Tags: system-installation

After installing Ubuntu, a report is sent to Canonical about my installation. I see two reports: `/var/log/installer/telemetry` and `~/.cache/ubuntu-report/Ubuntu.23.10`. The second one is much more complete.

Which of the two reports is sent?

Answer (score 2):

The one from `/var/log/installer/telemetry` is a 1-time sent document sent after installation. The one from ubuntu-report is a "pretty print" and comes from a manually started report (more about it on its [github](https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-report/tree/master))

[This](https://ubuntu.com/desktop/statistics) is the website that is created with this data.

In case you need to know what is sent [OMG Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/05/this-is-the-data-ubuntu-collects-about-your-system) had a story on it. The list:

```
Ubuntu version
OEM/Manufacturer
Device model number
BIOS info
CPU details
GPU details
Installed RAM
Partition Info
Display(s) details
Auto-login status
Live Patching status
Desktop environment
Display server
Timezone
```